# People should be wary of those who quote which author?

Tags: psycho-pass

In the anime Psycho Pass they reference some of the major ideologically leading people.

But there is a direct quote from one of the main characters saying "Be wary of those who quote ___"  There is then a reply: "Had you not quoted him I probably would have." Who is the author in question?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a trivia question, or do you actually have a question to ask?

Answer (score 10):

From episode 16 - The Gates Of Judgement (at around 16:10), Shogo Makishima said:

> Justice is subject to dispute; might is easily recognized and is not disputed. So we cannot give might to justice,

In return, Shinya Kogami replied:

> I have long since learned, as a measure of elementary hygiene, to be on guard when anyone quotes **Pascal**.

So the answer is Blaise Pascal.

By the way, Kogami's reply is actually a quote from [*Toward a Philosophy of History*](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=6U4naz5DfsgC&lpg=PA71&ots=RH0VoGXejm&pg=PA71) by José Ortega y Gasset.